# Why did Vichitravirya refuse to marry Amba?

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma

As per the Mahabharata Sabha Parva [Chapter 41](https://www.tititudorancea.com/z/mahabharata_shishupala_badha_parva.htm), while insulting Bhishma, Shishupala says as follows:

> O Bhishma, if you know Dharma, if your mind is guided by wisdom, why was that virtuous maiden Amba, who desired to have another for her husband, was forcibly carried away by you? **Your brother Vichitravirya who followed the path of the pious men,knowing her state of mind, did not marry her**, though she was brought by you?

What is the reason for Vichitravirya refusing to marry Amba?

Comment: Where do you get that view from?

Comment: It will be helpful if you quote these in your questions. Like as per Shishupalavadhaparva chapter x verse c the following has been written. Then ask your question. It’ll be helpful for those who know the answer to write so. If you want quote, I’ll help you format

Comment: @Adiyarkku [edited](https://www.tititudorancea.com/z/mahabharata_shishupala_badha_parva.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Vichitravirya did not reject Amba-

1. Amba requested Bhishma to allow her to go to Shalva:

> The ruler of the Salvas was before this mentally chosen by me as my lord. By him also, without my father’s knowledge, I was privately solicited. How wouldst you, O Bhishma, born especially as you are in Kuru’s race, transgress the laws of morality and cause one that longs for another to live in your abode? Knowing this, O bull of Bharata’s race, and deliberating in your mind, **it behoves you, O mighty-armed one, to accomplish what is proper**.
> -*Mahabharata Udyoga Parva [Section CLXXV](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc375113.html)*

2. Bhishma allowed her to go but Shalva rejected her:

> Unto her, however, O king, the  lord of the Salvas said with a laughter,
>
> 'O you of the fairest complexion, **I no longer desire to make a wife of you who wast to be wedded to another**. Therefore, O blessed one, go back thither unto Bhishma’s presence. I no longer desire you that was forcibly ravished by Bhishma. Indeed, when Bhishma, having vanquished the kings, took you away, you didst go with him cheerfully. 
> -*Mahabharata Udyoga Parva [Section CLXXVI](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc375114.html)*

3. Amba then blamed Bhishma and went to the forest:

> Human beings always suffer what is destined for them. **The cause, however, of my present affliction is Bhishma**, the son of Santanu; I, therefore, see that at present my vengeance should fall upon him, either through ascetic austerities or by battle, for he is the cause of my woe! But what king is there that would venture to vanquish Bhishma in battle?
>
> Having settled this, she issued out of the city for repairing to an asylum of the high-souled ascetics of virtuous deeds. The night she stayed there, surrounded by those ascetics.
> -*Mahabharata Udyoga Parva [Section CLXXVII](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc375115.html)*

So no, Vichitravirya did not reject Amba. Amba left with Bhishma permission and never came back to Hastinapura.